# How to run confluent-5.3.2-2.12 platform?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, ksqldb, confluent-platform

**Environment:**
CentOS7
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"

I downloaded `confluent-5.3.2-2.12.tar.gz` and extracted to `/opt/confluent`.

I am following "**Installing and Running KSQL | Level Up your KSQL by Confluent**" (https://youtu.be/icwHpPm-TCA).

Executed the following commands:

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# cd /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/
[root@srvr0 bin]# confluent start
bash: confluent: command not found...
```

Update1:

With reference to, https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-quickstart.html, executed the following commands:

```
curl -L https://cnfl.io/cli | sh -s -- -b /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin
/opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:latest
/opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/confluent local start
```

Logs:

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# curl -L https://cnfl.io/cli | sh -s -- -b /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0   162    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
100 10288  100 10288    0     0   3567      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 16176
confluentinc/cli info checking S3 for latest tag
confluentinc/cli info found version: latest for latest/linux/amd64
confluentinc/cli info NOTICE: see licenses located in /tmp/tmp.h8m7jASeAh/confluent
confluentinc/cli info installed /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/confluent
confluentinc/cli info please ensure /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin is in your PATH
[root@srvr0 ~]# cp /tmp/tmp.h8m7jASeAh/confluent
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/tmp/tmp.h8m7jASeAh/confluent’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
[root@srvr0 ~]# cp -a /tmp/tmp.h8m7jASeAh/confluent /opt/confluent
[root@srvr0 ~]# /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:latest
Running in a "--no-prompt" mode 
Implicit acceptance of the license below:  
Apache License 2.0 
https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
Downloading component Kafka Connect Datagen 0.2.0, provided by Confluent, Inc. from Confluent Hub and installing into /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/share/confluent-hub-components 
Adding installation directory to plugin path in the following files: 
  /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties 
  /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties 
  /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties 
  /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties 

Completed 
[root@srvr0 ~]# /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/confluent local start
    The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment
    only, NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.R3YJZ2UC
Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
kafka is [UP]
Starting schema-registry
schema-registry is [UP]
Starting kafka-rest
kafka-rest is [UP]
Starting connect
connect is [UP]
Starting ksql-server
ksql-server is [UP]
Starting control-center
|control-center failed to start
control-center is [DOWN]
```

**Update2:**

Logs:

```
[root@srvr0 confluent-5.3.2]# cat ./logs/controller.log
[2020-01-16 12:20:40,220] DEBUG preRegister called. Server=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@66d3c617, name=log4j:logger=kafka.controller (kafka.controller)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,097] INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=0] Starting (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,174] INFO [Controller id=0] 0 successfully elected as the controller. Epoch incremented to 1 and epoch zk version is now 1 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,176] INFO [Controller id=0] Registering handlers (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,182] INFO [Controller id=0] Deleting log dir event notifications (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,193] INFO [Controller id=0] Deleting isr change notifications (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,197] INFO [Controller id=0] Initializing controller context (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,361] INFO [Controller id=0] Initialized broker epochs cache: Map(0 -> 24) (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,370] DEBUG [Controller id=0] Register BrokerModifications handler for Set(0) (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,384] DEBUG [Channel manager on controller 0]: Controller 0 trying to connect to broker 0 (kafka.controller.ControllerChannelManager)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,444] INFO [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Starting (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,445] INFO [Controller id=0] Partitions being reassigned: Map() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,447] INFO [Controller id=0] Currently active brokers in the cluster: Set(0) (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,448] INFO [Controller id=0] Currently shutting brokers in the cluster: Set() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,448] INFO [Controller id=0] Current list of topics in the cluster: Set() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,449] INFO [Controller id=0] Fetching topic deletions in progress (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,456] INFO [Controller id=0] List of topics to be deleted:  (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,456] INFO [Controller id=0] List of topics ineligible for deletion:  (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,457] INFO [Controller id=0] Initializing topic deletion manager (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,458] INFO [Topic Deletion Manager 0] Initializing manager with initial deletions: Set(), initial ineligible deletions: Set() (kafka.controller.TopicDeletionManager)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,459] INFO [Controller id=0] Sending update metadata request (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,485] INFO [ReplicaStateMachine controllerId=0] Initializing replica state (kafka.controller.ZkReplicaStateMachine)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,487] INFO [ReplicaStateMachine controllerId=0] Triggering online replica state changes (kafka.controller.ZkReplicaStateMachine)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,518] INFO [ReplicaStateMachine controllerId=0] Triggering offline replica state changes (kafka.controller.ZkReplicaStateMachine)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,519] DEBUG [ReplicaStateMachine controllerId=0] Started replica state machine with initial state -> Map() (kafka.controller.ZkReplicaStateMachine)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,523] INFO [PartitionStateMachine controllerId=0] Initializing partition state (kafka.controller.ZkPartitionStateMachine)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,525] INFO [PartitionStateMachine controllerId=0] Triggering online partition state changes (kafka.controller.ZkPartitionStateMachine)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,535] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Controller 0's connection to broker srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) failed.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:71)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:295)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:249)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:89)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,539] DEBUG [PartitionStateMachine controllerId=0] Started partition state machine with initial state -> Map() (kafka.controller.ZkPartitionStateMachine)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,540] INFO [Controller id=0] Ready to serve as the new controller with epoch 1 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,542] INFO [Controller id=0] Removing partitions Set() from the list of reassigned partitions in zookeeper (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,543] INFO [Controller id=0] No more partitions need to be reassigned. Deleting zk path /admin/reassign_partitions (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,550] INFO [Controller id=0] Partitions undergoing preferred replica election:  (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,551] INFO [Controller id=0] Partitions that completed preferred replica election:  (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,553] INFO [Controller id=0] Skipping preferred replica election for partitions due to topic deletion:  (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,554] INFO [Controller id=0] Resuming preferred replica election for partitions:  (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,555] INFO [Controller id=0] Starting preferred replica leader election for partitions  (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,593] INFO [Controller id=0] Starting the controller scheduler (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,637] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Controller 0's connection to broker srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) failed.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:71)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:295)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:249)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:89)
[2020-01-16 12:21:40,738] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Controller 0's connection to broker srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) failed.
...
[2020-01-16 12:21:41,559] INFO [Controller id=0] New topics: [Set(__confluent.support.metrics)], deleted topics: [Set()], new partition replica assignment [Map(__confluent.support.metrics-0 -> Vector(0))] (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:41,559] INFO [Controller id=0] New partition creation callback for __confluent.support.metrics-0 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:41,653] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Controller 0's connection to broker srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) failed.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:71)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:295)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:249)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:89)
[2020-01-16 12:21:41,754] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Controller 0's connection to broker srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) failed.
...
[2020-01-16 12:21:45,596] INFO [Controller id=0] Processing automatic preferred replica leader election (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:45,597] TRACE [Controller id=0] Checking need to trigger auto leader balancing (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:45,601] DEBUG [Controller id=0] Preferred replicas by broker Map(0 -> Map(__confluent.support.metrics-0 -> Vector(0))) (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:45,605] DEBUG [Controller id=0] Topics not in preferred replica for broker 0 Map() (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:45,609] TRACE [Controller id=0] Leader imbalance ratio for broker 0 is 0.0 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:21:45,616] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Controller 0's connection to broker srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) failed.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.awaitReady(NetworkClientUtils.java:71)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:295)
    at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:249)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:89)
[2020-01-16 12:21:45,717] WARN [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Controller 0's connection to broker srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to srvr0:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) failed.
...
[2020-01-16 12:22:10,944] INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=0] Shutting down (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)
[2020-01-16 12:22:10,946] INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=0] Stopped (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)
[2020-01-16 12:22:10,946] INFO [ControllerEventThread controllerId=0] Shutdown completed (kafka.controller.ControllerEventManager$ControllerEventThread)
[2020-01-16 12:22:10,947] DEBUG [Controller id=0] Resigning (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:22:10,948] DEBUG [Controller id=0] Unregister BrokerModifications handler for Set(0) (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-01-16 12:22:10,951] INFO [PartitionStateMachine controllerId=0] Stopped partition state machine (kafka.controller.ZkPartitionStateMachine)
[2020-01-16 12:22:10,953] INFO [ReplicaStateMachine controllerId=0] Stopped replica state machine (kafka.controller.ZkReplicaStateMachine)
[2020-01-16 12:22:10,955] INFO [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Shutting down (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
[2020-01-16 12:22:10,956] TRACE [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] shutdownInitiated latch count reached zero. Shutdown called. (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
[2020-01-16 12:22:10,956] INFO [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Stopped (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
[2020-01-16 12:22:10,956] INFO [RequestSendThread controllerId=0] Shutdown completed (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)
[2020-01-16 12:22:10,960] INFO [Controller id=0] Resigned (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
```

Update 3:

Now, even worst... only zookeeper is starting. other services are failing to start...

Logs:

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/confluent local start
    The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment
    only, NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.R3YJZ2UC
Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
-Kafka failed to start
kafka is [DOWN]
Cannot start Schema Registry, Kafka Server is not running. Check your deployment
Error: exit status 127
[root@srvr0 ~]#
```

Update 4:

confluent local start, zookeeper-server-start and kafka-server-start logs:

```
[root@srvr0 ~]# /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/confluent local start
Updates are available for confluent. To install them, please run:
$ confluent update

    The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment
    only, NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.xgVLokw7
Starting zookeeper
zookeeper is [UP]
Starting kafka
|Kafka failed to start
kafka is [DOWN]
Cannot start Schema Registry, Kafka Server is not running. Check your deployment
Error: exit status 127

[root@srvr0 ~]# /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/zookeeper-server-start
USAGE: /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/zookeeper-server-start [-daemon] zookeeper.properties
[root@srvr0 ~]# /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/kafka-server-start
USAGE: /opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/kafka-server-start [-daemon] server.properties [--override property=value]*
```

server.properties hasn't been edited and its contents as follows:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000

##################### Confluent Metrics Reporter #######################
# Confluent Control Center and Confluent Auto Data Balancer integration
#
# Uncomment the following lines to publish monitoring data for
# Confluent Control Center and Confluent Auto Data Balancer
# If you are using a dedicated metrics cluster, also adjust the settings
# to point to your metrics kakfa cluster.
#metric.reporters=io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
#confluent.metrics.reporter.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
#
# Uncomment the following line if the metrics cluster has a single broker
#confluent.metrics.reporter.topic.replicas=1

##################### Confluent Proactive Support ###################### 
# If set to true, and confluent-support-metrics package is installed
# then the feature to collect and report support metrics
# ("Metrics") is enabled.  If set to false, the feature is disabled.
#
confluent.support.metrics.enable=true


# The customer ID under which support metrics will be collected and
# reported.
#
# When the customer ID is set to "anonymous" (the default), then only a
# reduced set of metrics is being collected and reported.
#
# Confluent customers
# -------------------
# If you are a Confluent customer, then you should replace the default
# value with your actual Confluent customer ID.  Doing so will ensure
# that additional support metrics will be collected and reported.
#
confluent.support.customer.id=anonymous

############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0


############################# Confluent Authorizer Settings  #############################

# Uncomment to enable Confluent Authorizer with support for ACLs, LDAP groups and RBAC
#authorizer.class.name=io.confluent.kafka.security.authorizer.ConfluentServerAuthorizer
# Semi-colon separated list of super users in the format <principalType>:<principalName>
#super.users=
# Specify a valid Confluent license. By default free-tier license will be used
#confluent.license=
# Replication factor for the topic used for licensing. Default is 3.
confluent.license.topic.replication.factor=1

# Uncomment the following lines and specify values where required to enable RBAC
# Enable RBAC provider 
#confluent.authorizer.access.rule.providers=ACL,RBAC
# Bootstrap servers for RBAC metadata. Must be provided if this broker is not in the metadata cluster
#confluent.metadata.bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
# Replication factor for the metadata topic used for authorization. Default is 3.
confluent.metadata.topic.replication.factor=1

# Listeners for metadata server
#confluent.metadata.server.listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8090
# Advertised listeners for metadata server
#confluent.metadata.server.advertised.listeners=http://127.0.0.1:8090
```

Please help me in resolving the issue!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where `srvr0:9092` is defined; I suggest reviewing your `server.properties` file to fix the connection strings.

You don't need to run `confluent` at all. You can follow the base Apache Kafka guides for running both Zookeeper and Kafka

`zookeeper-server-start` + `kafka-server-start`

Or you can use Confluent's APT/YUM repos rather than just extracting tarballs, then use systemctl to control services.

Or, using Docker is another way to get started quickly.

Comment: added section update 4 with server.properties file content

Comment: `/opt/confluent/confluent-5.3.2/bin/confluent local start` started all services except control centre, in 1st attempt. the services which were starting earlier, are also not starting now. no default settings/configurations have been changed. please help me!

Comment: host name is srvr0 (it can be observed from the terminal prompts also)